# Email client that allows adding pop account from cmd?

Tags: email, command-line-interface, pop3

I am looking for an email client that allows you to add all pop params:

email, server, password etc from cmd

At the moment our company uses OE but the ability to add a password is not there (the registry wants it as a REG_BINARY and even then points to a different registry location)

Is there an email client out there (free) that allows email accounts to be added in full from cmd?

Comment: Pine, Mutt, Thunderbird.  Do you really want to communicate passwords and the command line?  That sounds like a security disaster.

Comment: @Zoredache - it is just for configuring the computers - they wont be transmitted over any networks - I just need to script the account creation process.

Comment: Care to explain the downvote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thunderbird has a bunch of tools that allow some sort of centralized configuration: http://kb.mozillazine.org/Configuration_utilities_for_administrators.  I haven't tried these, so I don't know if they are suitable for what you want.

I suppose I can suggest curses-based Alpine (where, I suppose, you can centrally generated .pinerc files), but that may cause a rebellion amongst your users.